# Minimum element of each column in array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

An array of arrays is given. It is necessary to find the minimum element in each column and write the data to a new array. I have done the following implementation, in accordance with the given conditions. But I am having a problem:expected minimum element in each column of the array are incorrect. Where am I making a mistake?

```
class Program
    {
        static int[][] Input()
        {
            Console.Write("n = ");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int[][] a = new int[n][];
            //int[] minA = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                a[i] = new int[n];
                for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                {
                    Console.Write("a[{0},{1}]= ", i, j);
                    a[i][j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
        static void Print(int[] a)
        {
            foreach (double elem in a)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", elem);
            }
        }
        static void Print2(int[][] a)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i, Console.WriteLine())
                for (int j = 0; j < a[i].Length; ++j)
                    Console.Write("{0,5} ", a[i][j]);
        }
        static int[] F(int[][] a)
        {
            int[] b = new int[a[1].Length];
            for (int j = 0; j < a[1].Length; j++)
            {
                int tempmin = a[0][j];
                for (int i = 0; i < a[0].Length; i++)
                {
                    if (a[j][i] <= tempmin)
                    {
                        tempmin = a[j][i];
                        b[j] += tempmin;
                    }
                }
            }
            return b;
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int[][] myArray = Input();
            Print2(myArray);
            int[] b = new int[myArray.Length];
            b = F(myArray);
            Print(b);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you try rephrasing your question.  You start off by saying an array of `nxm [j]` is given.  I don't see an `nxm` type anywhere.  You talk about `mj` elements - I don't see that variable anywhere.  You say _the results of the minimum element in each column of the array are incorrect_, but you don't specify what you expect or what you are seeing.  Remember, we don't know your problem domain, and we really don't want to wade through code with a high cyclomatic complexity in order to understand the basics of your question.  The easier you make it for us, the more likely you get ...

Comment: @Flydog57, I have edited it a bit, I missed something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest looping over all `line`s, while tracking all `min` *columns* values:

```
using System.Linq; // for the final `ToArray()` 

...

private static int[] MinColumns(int[][] data) {
  if (null == data)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

  // List of columns' mins; initially the list is empty 
  List<int> list = new List<int>();

  // for each line (not column!) within jagged array...
  foreach (int[] line in data) {
    // let's just skip null lines (alternative is to throw exception)
    if (null == line)
      continue;

    // each new line can update columns' max values.
    // now we update each column
    for (int c = 0; c < line.Length; ++c)
      // if index c is too big, i.e.
      // the  line is too long and some columns appear first time...
      if (c >= list.Count)
        // ...we just add values of such columns as columns' min  
        for (int i = list.Count; i <= c; ++i)
          list.Add(line[i]);
      else
        // otherwise we update min values: we compare known min and current value 
        list[c] = Math.Min(list[c], line[c]);
  } 
  
  // finally, we convert list into array with ahelp of Linq 
  return list.ToArray(); 
}
```

Note, that here we *ignore* all holes, e.g. for

```
int[][] demo = new int[][] {
  new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4},
  new int[] {5, 6}, // <- hole: we don't have 3d and 4th columns here
  new int[] {7, 0, 8},
};
```

the answer will be `{Min(1, 5, 7), Min(2, 6, 0), Min(3, 8), Min (4)} = {1, 0, 3, 4}`

**Edit:** Usage is quite direct; something like this ([fiddle yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lAAl1v))

```
    static void Main()
    {
        // Get jagged array
        int[][] myArray = Input();
        // Print it
        Print2(myArray);
    
        // Get max for each column
        int[] b = MinColumns(myArray);
        // Print these maxes
        Print(b);
    }
```

Comment: can you show please how to integrate this code in my example?

Comment: @Parasha: `int[] b = MaxColumns(myArray);` will give you all the max values; then you, probably, will want to print them either with a help of `Print(b)` or `Console.Write(string,Join(" ", b));`

Comment: I received not max values, but all values from inputted array

Comment: @Parasha: you can fiddle youself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lAAl1v

Comment: @Parasha: do you have a *counter example*? I.e. `myArray` such that `MaxColumns` computes wrong max values?

Comment: Actually, I need min values, not max. I missed that

Comment: @Parasha: just change `Math.Max` into `Math.Min`; that's all

Comment: and the last question: can you explain a bit cycle foreach in your example?

Comment: @Parasha: we scan jagged array by lines - `foreach (int[] line in data)`, while either *add* columns' values as min ones (when column appears first time) or *update* known min value. I've added comments to the code, hope they'll help you to get the idea what's going on